# Sequelize/tedious table UPDATE on SQL Server 2005 table with triggers fails

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2005, sequelize.js, tedious

Using

- tedious 1.14
- sequelize 3.29
- node 6.9.4

Connecting to: SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Std

Node console output (attempted DML):

```
Executing (default): UPDATE [OtifOrders] SET [onTime]=N'Short Lead Time / Add On',[inFull]=N'Product Substitution' OUTPUT INSERTED.* WHERE [orderNumber] = N'1024098924-1'
PATCH /api/otiforders/1024098924-1 500 302.990 ms - -
```

SQL Server error message from profiler:

> The target table OtifOrders of the DML statement cannot have any
>   enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without
>   INTO clause.

Anyone else ran into this, how did you get around it?

Not 100% sure this is tedious...

Cheers

Comment: You mean other than changing the trigger to not use `OUTPUT INSERTED.*`, as the error message suggests? Triggers happen behind the scenes and shouldn't have output like that, and in fact there is a server-level setting that prohibits it entirely. If you don't have control over that trigger, then take that error message to the vendor of tedious or sequelize or whatever you're using and ask them to fix it. Again, why a trigger would `OUTPUT INSERTED.*` except during desperate debugging, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

Crap,
Why is it always like that - as soon as I post the question to a forum I find the answer and it's right on front of my nose.

Anyway, here it is: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4807
AsientosContables_sql = sequelize.define('AsientosContables_sql', {  }, { tableName: 'Asientos', **hasTrigger: true** });