# How to prevent the sequelize from creating the output clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When I do a create using sequelize it returns me the response i.e. the newly created entry row in the response,

Sequelize Create Object Code:

```
let createdObj= await sequelize.ModelName.create(modelObject,{ transaction :t, //more options can be added here, need some value of option that prevents the output inserted  })
```

Below is the query created:
`INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] ([COL1],[COL2],[COL3],[COL4]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)`

Now I don't want the output clause to be part of the query, I want a simple insert like:

`INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] ([COL1],[COL2],[COL3],[COL4]) VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)`
I don't want the output clause to be part of the query.

How can I achieve this in at the query level as well as at the model level? In some Create operations, I want the output clause and in some create operations, I don't want.

**EDIT 1**
On Further research I found an option called `{ returning: false }` this does what is required i.e. create an insert query like this `INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] ([COL1],[COL2],[COL3],[COL4]) VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)` but now the Sequelize is breaking because it's expecting those values back in return idk why?

```
C:\Users\MG265X1\project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:389
      id = id || results && results[0][this.getInsertIdField()];
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Query.handleInsertQuery (C:\Users\MG265X1\project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:389:39)
```

Turns out if an autoIncrementAttribute is present in the model, it will look for the output clause, removing the attribute `{autoIncrement: true }` from the model hasn't helped as IDENTITY_INSERT cannot be null. How do I move ahead on this??

**Edit 2** I could get it working with a combination of `{ returning: false }` and `{hasTriggers: true}`. Have `hasTriggers` Attribute as `true` in your Model, this will allow you to single creates but for bulk Creates pass option `returning: false` at the time of bulkCreate.

***Note***: When using bulkCreate with `{ returning: false }` you'll not be able to get the autogenerated Id, It's a trade-off that we had to live with as we want
bulkCreate to work with triggers, we ended up fetching the Id later from DB

Seems I raised [this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12384) but was closed as it wasn't `good SSCCE`

Comment: What you wrote here is not "code", please post the code that you're using, the response and etc.

Comment: a very basic insert. let me just add that

Comment: I don't see any result returned from the call...

Comment: the problem is not with what is returned, the problem is I don't want values to be returned, the reason values are returned is because of the `output clause` in insert query created by sequelize, I don't want that output clause to be appended to the query.

Comment: It's not clear what is that "output", are you referring to a `console.log` output?

Comment: If yes, try to add to the options (second parameter that you're passing in) the following: `logging: false`

Comment: Not the logging but the SQL created by Sequelize  `INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] ([COL1],[COL2],[COL3],[COL4]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)` 

The `OUTPUT INSERTED` in the SQL here.

Comment: I feel like we're in the [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. You're not explaining what you want to achieve properly and keep focusing on the "how". It's not clear to me _what_ is this _output_ you're talking about, _how_ does it affect the INSERT and _why_ don't you want it. I've tried along several comments to cooperate with you but we keep running into a "dead end" because you're focusing the question on the _way_ instead of the _target_. Good luck!

Comment: Hint: "I don't want it" without a valid reason is not helpful...

Comment: Ah ohk, we've a common DB that's used some of the applications made using java, Spring Boot to be precise, there the JDBCTemplate doesn't create an output response, also the python apps don't create the output clause on insert,our DB Admin has some complex computed columns and triggers that don't work with the output clause, and since existing applications have not a problem with it so the new Node Application also shouldn't have those problems. As a result we want to remove the output clause, before you say look at  `hasTriggers: true` option, let me tell you it doesn't work with bulk create.

Comment: Ok, this is much more informative, thanks!
Please update the question with all that input, link to other relevant questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577879/sequelize-tedious-table-update-on-sql-server-2005-table-with-triggers-fails) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577879/sequelize-tedious-table-update-on-sql-server-2005-table-with-triggers-fails) and explain why it's not solving your use-case.